# Divisibility is only defined for abelian group?

Tags: group-theory, modules, definition, abelian-groups

This question is maybe too simple, but I am just wondering. In the study of modules, divisible group is introduced, but specifically only for abelian groups (in Hungerford, for example). Something like: "An abelian group $G$ is called divisible if for each $a\in G$ and nonzero integer $n$, there is $b\in G$ such that $a=nb$"

It seems like it can also be defined for non abelian groups.
I have searched in other sources but could not understand the main reason. I know modules are abelian groups, but is that the only reason why divisibility is introduced only for abelian groups in such textbook? I mean, usually if it can, author will just define it for general group by simply removing the word "abelian", and then use it for abelian groups without problem, right? Maybe there is another reasoning I miss.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The notion of divisible group *is* defined for nonabelian groups. For example, there is work on when a nilpotent group can be embedded in a divisible nilpotent group.

Comment: But there is no point in going on excursions about arbitrary group when you work with modules, because the only groups that show up in the study of modules are abelian groups (both the additive structure of the module and of the ring). There is no point in introducing a much more general definition for arbitrary groups when you will never consider it except in the context of abelian groups. Moreover, to introduce it for arbitrary groups you need multiplicative notation, that you will immediately abandon in favor of additive. Why bother?

Comment: $x\mapsto x^n$ is usually not an homomorphism for non-abelian groups, that $G$ is abelian is the same as $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is an homomorphism, if $x\mapsto x^n,x\mapsto x^{n+a}$ both are homomorphisms then $x^n$ commutes with $y^a$

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I am just confused with the introduction. Maybe this is just about the textbook. Even though it can be defined for general group, usually math books I read will do something like "A certain object has this property if .... This notion can be generalized to a more general object, but we are interested in this certain object", or, while introducing groups before modules, the divisibility can be introduced earlier multiplicatively. Both are done just to avoid unnecessary confusion arising from small curiosity :) So from this point of view, I think it makes sense if I bother :D

Comment: Again, the problem is that to even mention that you can define it for more general objects, you would need to give big caveats about notation, which makes the addition both awkward and unwieldly.

Comment: In addition, divisible abelian groups have a very important role in abelian group theory: you can decompose an abelian group into a direct sum of divisible plus reduced groups, divisible abelian groups have a well-understood structure (copies of $\mathbb{Q}$ and Prufer $p$-groups), and they have an important categorical property that transaltes to an important property of modules (they are "injective" in the category of abelian groups). None of these facts hold for arbitrary groups, so the concept becomes much less fruitful in that context. Again, the generality doesn't help, it hinders.

Comment: Thanks. In that case it still is also better if a textbook puts a short one sentence explanation, such as "Although this definition of divisibility does not concern about the fact that the group is abelian, we shall see some important results in studying modules" or something, as a new and curious readers might question the definition before knowing the whole importance.

Comment: This is what I mean for example: "A vector space $A$ is said to be blablabla if all subspaces of $A$ satisfies certain properties." The term "vector space" is necessary because then we could not talk about subspace. Remove that and it becomes meaningless, right? If instead this "blablabla" definition is to mean that "every homomorphic image of $A$ has certain properties", it is fine too as in the divisibility case, but then to avoid unnecessary awkwardness (because homomorphic image can be defined for modules), it will be better by defining that for modules and then add "In particular, ...

Comment: ... we get the following results for blablabla vector space $A$". In this example, assume that this "certain properties" can also be defined for modules.

Comment: In fact, when defining free modules, the Hungerford textbook adds such notes. It defines that the ring has unity, the proceeds to mention that it is possible to define free over rings with no unity, and adds "Unless stated otherwise, ..." and so on. It should be able to do the same for divisibility, with even shorter explanation.